# Substitute power supply for batteries in motor controller

Tags: power-supply

I'm rigging up a demo stand that will use a (large) model RC car. We can't use its batteries since we can't get to the unit to recharge, so we're using a power supply instead. The requirement is for about 10V at about 20A.

One obvious issue is that these cars use regenerative braking, great for batteries but not so much for a power supply. I plan to put a large capacitor bank on the DC leads to soak up the back EMF -- should I take any other measures?

Would a common open-frame switching supply be OK here, or is there a better type of supply for this purpose?

Comment: It depends which "a common open-frame" supply you pick. A 20A motor will likely have 100-200A start-up currents, which RC batteries typically can provide, but a common 20-A supply can't.

Comment: @AliChen Thanks. I had figured that the capacitor bank would help with starting current as well. Do you know of a source of power supplies that might be suitable?

Comment: If you can permanently connect a power supply, what's stopping you from permanently connecting a charger, and leave the batteries in place?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Thanks for your thoughts. The question is whether the charger could withstand the operating current, let alone the starting current. Back EMF can be handled with a diode. I can look for a charger that wouldn't be affected by running into a load that would sometimes look like a short circuit. (-:

Comment: @BrianDrummond - On further reflection and searching, I don't think this is feasible. No chargers I can find want to operate "in circuit" with LiPo cells, especially not (as in this case) two packs in parallel. If you know otherwise, I'm open to pursuing it further.